# create an array and exclude objects ending with :

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm having following array that i would like to filter so that all objects ending with `:` should be removed. is there an easy way to do this for instance implementing in the filter which is already there?

```
var ingredientsArray = ingredients.replace(/<strong>[\s\S]*?<\/strong>/g, '').split('<br>').map(it => it.trim()).filter(it => !!it)
```

This could create an array like for instance

```
["fruits:", "1 lime", "2 lemons"]
```

then i want to filter out to the objects with `:` to

```
["1 lime", "2 lemons"]
```

Comment: Where is the Array? Can you please create a snippet with a [mcve]

Comment: i've added something now

Comment: Why not add the criteria to the map or filter statement?

Comment: @PeterPik did you found any answer helpful?

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
["fruits:", "1 lime", "2 lemons"].filter(x => !x.endsWith(':'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ES5 only, try something like this:

```
var ingredientsArray = ingredients.replace(/<strong>[\s\S]*?<\/strong>/g, '').split('<br>')

var filteredArray = ingredientsArray.reduce(function(acc, item) {
  item = item.trim()
  if (item) {
    if (item[item.length - 1] !== ':') {
      acc.push(item)
    }
  }

  return acc
}, [])
```

With latest nodejs you can use answer of **CD..** or a bit improved version:

```
const filteredArray = ingredientsArray.reduce((acc, item) => {
  item = item.trim()

  if (item && item.endsWith(':')) {
    acc.push(item)
  }

  return acc
}, [])
```